# Conservative vector field. Line integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

everyone! I hope you can help me with this problem about conservative vector fields. The exercise I am trying to solve is the following:

**Consider the vector field
$f = (x \cdot \ln(x^2+y^2)-y,Q(x,y))$
where $Q$ satisfies $Q(0,y) = 2 \cdot y \cdot \ln \lvert y \rvert $**

*Can f be conservative? In those cases, determine the line integral of $f$ where $C$ is any path going from the origin to $(a,b)$.*

If $f$ is conservative, it is clear to me that the line integral is path-independent and could be solved using the scalar potential function of $f$ and then evaluate it in $(0,0)$ and $(a,b)$ correctly. However, I don´t know how to use the condition for $Q$ to answer the question. Also, not having the explicit expression of $Q$ makes it difficult to find the scalar potential function.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For viewers, let's recall that $f=(P,Q)$ is a **conservative** vector field on an open and simply connected set $D$ if:

1. $\nabla P$ and $\nabla Q$ are continuous
2. The rotational of $f$ is null. In two dimensions, this condition can be expressed as $\det(\nabla,f) = 0$ or $\partial_x Q = \partial_y P$.

Therefore and according to Poincaré's Lemma, there exists a scalar potential s.t. $f = \nabla\phi$.
If we take any path $C$ from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$, we can actually write $C$ as the image of a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-vector field $\gamma$, defined on $[0,1]$ as long as $\gamma(0) = (0,0)$ and $\gamma(1) = (a,b)$:

$$
C = \left\lbrace\gamma(t),\quad t\in[0,1]\right\rbrace,\quad
\gamma(0) = (0,0),\quad
\gamma(1) = (a,b)
$$

We can study the path integral functional $F[\gamma] := \int_\gamma\left\langle f(x),dx\right\rangle$.
In the specific case of a conservative vector field, every point of the $C$ path can be bijectively expressed as the image of an element $t\in[0,1]$.
We thus make the change of variable $\gamma(t) = x$, yielding:

$$
F[\gamma] =
\int_0^1\left\langle f\circ\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)\right\rangle dt = \int_0^1\left\langle \nabla\phi\circ\gamma(t),\gamma'(t)\right\rangle dt = \int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}\left(\phi\circ\gamma(t)\right) dt
=\phi(a,b) - \phi(0,0)
$$

where the third equality comes from the chain rule.
We see that the functional only depends on the start and end of the path, finding the scalar potential is sufficient.

---

Let's suppose that $f$ is a conservative vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Thus the potential scalar field is given by $\partial_x\phi = P$ and $\partial_y\phi = Q$:

$$
\phi(a,b) -\phi(0,0) =
\phi(a,b) -\phi(0,b) + \phi(0,b) -\phi(0,0) =
\int_0^a P(s,b) ds + \int_0^b Q(0,s) ds
$$

You actually don't need the full expression of $Q$ in this specific case.
The last step is to compute the integrals.

Comment: Interesting approach. I will try the exercise that way. Thank you for your help!